# How does ath9k introduce itself to mac80211?

Tags: kernel, drivers

My question is about Linux kernel and ath9k wireless driver:

1. How does ath9k announce itself to the mac80211?
2. How come the mac80211 knows how to configure ath9k?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the modern kernel, devices are described via the device tree.  The device tree will contain a description of various hardware elements and names of their respective drivers.  When a device matches a device tree entry, the device driver associated with it is alerted.  The device driver then probes the device to test capabilities.

[mac80211 is a framework made available for writing wireless drivers](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/mac80211).  ath9k is the driver the kernel loads to interface with the card

Comment: Dear, could you please more specific and refer to the code, where exactly this "match" happen?

Comment: They're defined in the kernel, under arch/[your architecture].  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to answer the question I have been asked! Could you please help me out